# Indefinite Integral $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{-{{x}^{2}}-{{a}^{2}}}}dx}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate this integral $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{-{{x}^{2}}-{{a}^{2}}}}dx}$ but, unfortunately, so far, I haven’t found a suitable substitution. A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The denominator is not defined  as  a real number.  As a  complex number it has two values for each $x$. So the question does not make sense.

Comment: Of course we integrate over the complex numbers.  A sum of squares suggests a substitution.  An answer below uses hyperbolic function, we can instead use trigonometric and get $$\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{-x^2-a^2}}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} \text{arcsinh}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. The integral becomes $$\frac{1}{i} \int \frac{d}{dx} \text{arcsinh}{\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}dx = -i \text{ arcsinh}{\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)} + C.$$

Comment: That’s a fair point. Perhaps there’s a trig function instead of a hyperbolic?

Comment: @Gabrielė you might use the identity $ i\sinh{x} = \sin{ix}$ to get the answer in a trigonometric form.

Comment: Thank you very much!